# What are the different ways to pass parameters between pages using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, el

what are different practices to pass parameters between two pages other than by using query parameters and global variables in javascript?

Comment: You can call a function of one page from other page by passing the parameter you need ..

Comment: Use cookie or local storage

Comment: I have no idea why would someone upvoted this question, anyway what's wrong with `querystring`?

Comment: @Bhargavi: there are lot of SO questions that can answer your question. Please do some homework before asking an question

Comment: @gdoron i can't use query params as i want clean urls

Comment: @555k i want to know practices other than cookies,storage(local or session), query params and global variables

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can pass a parameter to another page in several different ways:

- by storing the parameter in a cookie
- by storing the parameter in a  JavaScript variable of another window
  or frame
- by storing the  parameter in the rewritable property top.name (the
  browser window    name)
- by appending the parameter to the destination page's URL as a
  query string

I reffered this [**site**](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/passingp.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 choices I think

1. Use a server side script and pass parameter as request parameter to the new page
2. Use cookies to store the values locally
3. if you are looking for a html5 solution use [sessionStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-webstorage-20091222/#the-sessionstorage-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

You can use DOM storage (or even cookies) to store information.

This allows the data to be read from any page on the same domain.

DOM storage comes in a couple of flavours so you can choose to store the information for the session or permanently (until the user clears it).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage